# Getting months based on the year input

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get the All months based on the year input upto march only

Suppose:-If the year is 2018 then i need to get all the months starting  from October(Next month from the current month) to April only.

Because these values i need to pass to sp to get the table data
If the year is 2017 then i need all months.
please help me

Comment: Are you looking for a stored procedure specifically?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No, I tried to get the month names upto march based on the current date but i need to get those month names by year input

Comment: To ask again, do want a proc, a query, or maybe a function?

Comment: query is better because i want to pass those result to an sp something like that.

Comment: Have you got some test data we can use to help you out? You can use something like sqlfiddle, here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/409a1/16

Comment: If you have 2017 as an year, what is your expected output - numbers form 1 to 12?

Comment: Not really, i want month names like jan-dec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be below query will help you.

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @Year int= 2018     --Finanical year 
SET @StartDateTime = CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(20))+'-04-01' as datetime)
SET @EndDateTime =  CAST(CAST(@Year+1 AS VARCHAR(20))+'-03-31' as datetime)
;WITH DateRange(Dates) AS 
(
SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
Union ALL
SELECT DATEADD(d,1,Dates)
FROM DateRange 
WHERE Dates < @EndDateTime
)
Select   distinct DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(dates) , 0 ) - 1 ) as monthname
    ,year(dates) as year
    , month(dates) as monthnumber
from DateRange
where 
    (Year(GETDATE())=@Year AND  DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, getdate()), 0)<dates)
    OR
    (Year(GETDATE())<>@Year )
order by year(dates), month(dates)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```